# Remove many package together, if some of them not found, skip and remove others

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall

For the simplest example, if I want to remove two package, a and b. I do this:

```
sudo apt purge --autoremove package-a package-b
```

If ubuntu doesn't found package-a , it will stop and complain. How to let it automatically skip the package it can't find and just remove the ones it finds?

Suppose I have a lot of package to remove but I don't know which of them are actually in system, therefore I found skipping the "unfound" is very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is to do it with:

```
dpkg --r package-a package-b
```

I found it here: https://superuser.com/questions/518859/ignore-packages-that-are-not-currently-installed-when-using-apt-get-remove .

Comment: It will not work in `package-a` has other packages as dependency, those will remain, as it was indicated in a comment on that answer. The better way is this one http://superuser.com/a/725120/134448